# Query of the association performed with the same id with the source query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails project with some models and their associations.
I'm facing a problem that occurs when I use includes () on a find, example:

```
ModelOne
 has_one :model_two

ModelTwo
```

When i do ModelOne.includes(:model_two).find(1)
Rails use "1" to query the id from both, example:

```
select * from ModelOne where id = 1
select * from ModelTwo where id = 1
```

But there is no ModelTwo with id = 1

Comment: If `ModelOne` has only one `ModelTwo`, why aren't you doing `ModelOne.find_by(id: 1).model_two`? Why all that `includes` business?

Comment: but does your I want to access an attribute within ModelTwo?

Comment: `ModelOne.find_by(id: 1).model_two.some_attribute` BTW, that degree of chaining violates the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter#In_object-oriented_programming). But, since we don't know what your code looks like, we can't help you with that.

Comment: Thats does not work, without includes() model_two is only a id attribute.

Comment: I suspect you have something set up incorrectly with your associations. By definition, `ModelOne.find(id: 1).model_two` will return either `nil` or an instance of `ModelTwo` (if you have things set up correctly). The fact that it is returning an integer suggests that something is amiss. Could be you have your foreign key on the wrong model. Could be that your `has_one` and `belongs_to` are reversed. IDK, could be something else. But, you don't show us much, so difficult to know.

Comment: You need to show more code. Show your full models. Show your db schema.

Comment: I still can not solve the problems.
However, I believe it links to wrong associations and the database schema itself.
The problem is that this project is being created on top of a database of another application, which was probably generated using hibernate.
To make it more readable I made some modifications like adding alias_attribute in the models.
How everything runs away from the Rails conventions is very likely to be that.